# where clause on parameter but if blank return all including null

Tags: sql-server-2008, null, where-clause

I'm extracting data on `SQL Server 2008 R2` (and using the script in a `Microsoft excel` query in the end). The query has a number of `where` clauses based on parameters that will be in `excel cells`.

However I have an issue with the script simply designing in `management studio` where we want a parameter to be allowed to leave blank.
Though if I do this it returns only values not `nulls`.
I need something along the lines:

```
WHERE ....
AND ND.Title = CASE WHEN @param1 = 'blank' 
                    THEN "Return all including null" 
                    ELSE "Return" @param1
```

But I cannot work out how to achieve this.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Perhaps include an example input and output.

Answer (score 2):

Her is how you can do this:

```
WHERE .... AND (ND.Title = @param1 OR @param1 = '' OR @param1 IS NULL)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this returns everything excluding nulls where the parameter is empty/blank. it must be able to return Null rows also.

Comment: @Ad83, I don't know what you are passing as `@param1`, but see edits.

Comment: @param1 is a varchar  that would be one of 4 option sales,cos,personnel,expenses if none of these are valid the row would contain a null. The update still randomly won't return the null rows? though it certainly seems like it should.

Comment: Aha i think its working just started to copy over the full where clause and there was a conflict with what you had suggested still in there. I'll go test now and close/rate this answer asap.

Comment: @Ad83, you are welcome. You can just leave `(ND.Title = @param1 OR @param1 IS NULL)` if you pass NULL as mark to select all rows

Comment: Ah it does work in mgmt studio perfectly however in Excel query i'm getting 'bad parameter type' errors but i have the cell that is referenced by the parameter as text format. code is now AND (ND.[TITLE] = ? or ? = N'' or ?  IS NULL )

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the `CASE` clause syntax. Have it this way:

```
WHERE ....
AND ND.Title = CASE WHEN @param1 = 'blank' 
                    THEN "Return all including null" 
                    ELSE "Return" END
```